# How can I combine two tables with my Eloquent query?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

We work on a database where table names are named locally.

```
table.product
-- id
-- picture
-- category_id

table.category
-- id
-- caterory_name
-- category_directory
```

There are some products in table. `product.category_id` should point `category.id` so system will understand that product belongs to desired table.

We could do this by using INNER JOIN but we can't do it with Laravel. We probably need to configure our models with has/belongs_to etc.

This is where we struggle.

```
//Controller
$products = Product::all();

return View::make('theme-admin.product_list')
    ->with('products', $products);

//View (in foreach)
{{ URL::to('uploads/categories/[NEED_CATEGORY.CATEGORY_DIRECTORY_HERE]/' . $products[$k]->picture) }}
```

We can't get `Category.category_directory` info in our views since we pass `Product::all()` only.

How can we make it so the $products array also contains `category.category_directory` for each value and we can access it like; $products[$k]->category_name?

Thanks!

Comment: Did my suggestion below work??  The first way that I offered was gonna query the database multiple times in a loop, but you must also realise that even if you setup a relationship, it still runs multiple queries, you solve that by eager loading.....let me know if that helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a category relation in your Product model:

```
class Product extends Eloquent {

  private $table = 'myProductsTableName';

  public function category()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'myCategoryColumnID');
  }

}

class Category extends Eloquent {

  private $table = 'myCategoriesTableName';

}
```

Unless you need to select all products from a particular category, you don't need to create a hasMany relation on your Category model.

And you just need to use myCategoryColumnID if your products table doesn't follow the singular_table_name_id rule (product_id).

Then just use it:

```
//View (in foreach)
{{ URL::to('uploads/categories/'.$products[$k]->category->category_directory.'/' . $products[$k]->picture) }}
```

Comment: Getting exception "Trying to get property of non-object." By the way, is Category inside category() function the name of Model or database table name? My database table names are slightly different, because they're localised and I translated them just for posting on stackoverflow. Concept remains the same though.

Comment: I combined some of the response from yours and above answerers and found myself the solution. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

I would setup a relationship...

```
class Product extends Eloquent {

 public function category()
 {
  return $this->belongsTo('Category');
 }

 }

class Category extends Eloquent {

 public function product()
 {
  return $this->hasMany('Product');
 }

 }
```

The name you use in the realtionship is the Model name.....so be sure if you're using a different table name than your model name, that you set that in your model

```
protected $table = "yourtablename";
```

Then use it like so...

```
{{ URL::to('uploads/categories/'.$products[$k]->category->category_directory.'/'
```

You still end up querying the database multiple times this way... This is called the N+1 effect. Example, if you have 5 products, one query will be executed to get those products. Then in the loop we are executing a query to get the category. This results in 6 total queries.

To solve this problem, use eager loading, which reduces those 6 queries in our example down to 2.

```
 $products = Product::with('category')->get();
```

Then send that to your view, where you can do your foreach loop..

```
 foreach($products as $val){
 //To output the directory
 echo $val->category->category_directory;

 }
```

Or in blade...

```
@foreach($products as $val)
{{URL::to('uploads/categories/'.$val->category->category_directory.'/'.$val->picture)}}
@endfor
```

Comment: Views are not supposed to know much about your models, they should receive data to be shown, not querying database tables and pull data from them.

Comment: Sorry thats my bad....its get() not all(), refer here  http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading

Comment: No problemo, its a nice way to significantly reduce the amount of queries....hope it works out for you....you may also want to just change your foreach loop to @foreach($urunler as $k)  then you just access like $k->kategori->kategori_klasoru  instead of the whole $products[$k] thing